# Override the default password length when creating or updating a user profile

Tags: password

I may be missing something. My understanding is `wp_generate_password` is pluggable. When I run the function below, it doesn't change the password length in the display when adding a new user or modifying a current user.

```
function wp_password() {

    // Modify the args supplied to wp_generate_password
    $args = array(
        'length'              => '100',
        'special_chars'       => true,
        'extra_special_chars' => false,
    );
    
    wp_generate_password ($args);
}
apply_filters( 'wp_generate_password', 'wp_password' );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Pluggable" means that you actually replace the complete function with your own of the same name, e.g. you call it `wp_generate_password` and have it do the same thing as the original function, with whatever modifications you want.

I don't see a filter for modifying the args in the way you are describing, but you can modify the output if you want, using `random_password`.

It might help to [see the source code here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_generate_password/) to get a deeper understanding of what is going on. Hope that helps!

Comment: You'd have to do something to actually change the value of `$password` before you return it — then you should see a difference!

Comment: shouldn't it be passing the default value of $password?

Comment: Not if you want to change the length of the generated password that the user gets. By passing the original `$password`, you're sending the original generated password to the user. Does that make sense?

To make the length longer, you'd actually have to have code to generate a longer password within the `my_random_password()` function. By the time the `random_password` filter runs, the password has already been generated.

Comment: Wouldn't that cause an infinite loop? Since `wp_generate_password()` is with this filter essentially being told to run itself. But if in `my_random_password()` you remove the filter, I think it could work. You could add it back again after running `wp_generate_password()`.

Comment: It's a little weird, but it works :). It's not literally hacky in the sense that it would cause odd side-effects or be hard to maintain.